# Convert unsigned char to unsigned short (big endian)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a LabVIEW program (not mine) which save data (uint16) in a binary file like this:
[image]

- Split the number by 2^8 to get 2 uint8 (for example 320 = 256 + 64)
- Switch the data before to save (so here begin with 64 and finish with 256)

It is why I read 4 octets to get 2 unsigned short

```
ifstream is("filename", ifstream::binary);
if (is) {
    is.seekg(0, is.end);

    unsigned char data_char[4];
    unsigned short data;

    is.seekg(376, is.beg);
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(width), sizeof(width));

    // What I tried (switch and convert)
    data = data_char[1]<<24 + data_char[0]<<16 + data_char[3]<<8 + data_char[2];
}
```

For example the value 320 (uint8) is saved in the file and when I read data_char I have an unsigned char with the 4 composants of the number :

- [0] = 0 '\0'
- [1] = 64 '@'
- [2] = 1 '\x1'
- [3] = 0 '\0'

And with 256 I have :

- [0] = 1 '\x1'
- [1] = 0 '\0'
- [2] = 0 '\0'
- [3] = 0 '\0'
  The [0] and [1] is the first uint8 and [2] and [3] the second.

But, being a novice in C++, I tried a bit shift to convert the char to a short, but I am not doing the right way.

I know for you it is something easy but an you help me please ?

For information, in Python I just have to do: `sum(struct.unpack(">HH", f.read(4))`

Comment: I'd recommend to use `htons()`/`ntohs()` to do that.

Comment: Haven't you written the answer yourself `data_char[2]*256 + data_char[1]`? You don't have to do it with a bit shift.

Comment: Yes but this solution admits that I have always my data on 2d and 3th index of my char. So it is not universal. I sais that because after I have to read other data in little endian and uint16 so I have to understand the bases first ;)

Comment: Well the answer is always `second_byte*256 + first_byte`. That is universal.

Comment: Ok so for example, 256 will be 1, 0, 0, 0. If I do what you suggest, I find 0.

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin you said `short` and why are you converting 4 bytes?

Comment: You right, I wrote a mistake. My number is saved with two unsigned short. Sorry

Comment: "My number is saved with two unsigned short." what does that mean?

Comment: I'm confused, so is the OP I guess.

Comment: OP means? ^^ It is my colleague who wrote the LabVIEW program who did something weird.

Comment: You need to make your mind and fix your question. I believe common meaning of octet is 8bits, so if you have different meaning explain that without confusing terms.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it is because I read 4 characters with the read function, and I confused myself with the number of bytes read by this function.

Comment: _"I am not doing the right way."_ Okay, which way are you doing it and why/how do you think/know it is not right? We can't correct code we can't see.

Comment: "We can see : 1*2^8 + 64 = 320" no we cannot. Can you explain how you see that?

Comment: Ok I clarify my post and post what I tried. I finally was able to talk with my colleague by phone.

Comment: I do not quite understand your encodings, and value 320 cannot fit `uint8`. What you describe is 2 byte of data stored in 4 bytes in some weird format.

Comment: I think you should tell your manager that they need reevaluate your colleague's ability to work as a developer.

Comment: Lol, this colleague does LabVIEW from 15 years but is not a programmer ^.^ Yes 320 fit on a uint16 and (I edited my post) he split it into two uint8.

Comment: I added another example to show how weird it is. With Python, I just have to do `sum(struct.unpack(">HH", f.read(4))`

Comment: This encoding is created by mentally challenged, sorry I give up.

Comment: Don't worry. thanks for your participation, I found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert big endian to native endian, simply shift the bytes by bitwidth of the byte times the difference<sup>†</sup> of byte position and the size of integer and combine everything with bitwise or.

<sup>†</sup> More specifically: first byte shifted most significantly, last byte is not shifted at all.

```
template<class T>
T my_ntoh(unsigned char* buf) {
    const auto s = sizeof(T);
    T value = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s; i++)
        value |= buf[i] << CHAR_BIT * (s - 1 - i);
    return value;
}
```

This template will work with any size integer and will read as many bytes as is the size of the integer type.

If you can rely on POSIX, it provides `ntohs`, so you don't have to write this conversion yourself.

---

Since you want to read two big endian unsigned shorts and add them together (I use `uint16_t` since it's guaranteed to be 2 octets):

```
auto part1 = my_ntoh<uint16_t>(data_char);
auto part2 = my_ntoh<uint16_t>(data_char + sizeof part1);
data = part1 + part2;
```

Comment: This solution is quite cool. The only problem (I edited my post) is I saw that there are a switching of bytes during the save. But don't delete your answer because it could be apply in another place of my code ^^

Comment: Looks like OP has little-endian encoding where each byte is 16 bits, lol. Actually no, `unsigned short` is splitted into two bytes and each stored as unsigned short. Weirdo

Comment: I know, I added two examples like this you can see what I can get after reading. And I added what I do in Python to get the good result.

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin Ah, you want to read 2 shorts :) Now I understand. I was also confused earlier and my function converted from little endian actually. This should now be correct.

Comment: It is working, but I don't understand why we have to do a complex thing this way instead of something like `data = (data_char[2]<<8 | data_char[3]) | (data_char[0]<<8 | data_char[1])` ?

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin you can do it like that if you want to. That's exactly what my program does, except my function can be used to read other sized integers as well. And except I use + instead of | to combine the parts since it isn't clear to me whether | makes sense there. Result is same as long as the two parts don't share any set bits. However, to me your line looks like a magic incantation. From my function calls I clearly see that I read and convert two consecutive shorts and add them together.

Comment: Yeah I see. thank you very much. I begin in C++ so I have a lot to learn ;)

Comment: If I want to do the same but with little endian, I have to use `>>` instead of `<<` ?

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin no. Direction of shift is always to left. For little endian, you shift last byte most and first byte not at all. So in my function replace `s - 1 - i` with `i`.

Comment: Last question ^^ Why using a template instead of a standard function ?

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin because it supports returning integers of different types: unsigned versions of short, int, long and long long and implementation defined ones. A non-template function can have only one return type.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using the special *standard* functions to do that. Take a look at `htons()` and `ntohs()` (host-to-network and network-to-host short). It is no trouble to find a documentation on them online (specific to your system), here's one such page: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/htonsman.html

Comment: But this is quite good if at the start it was saved on a standard way, what is not in my case.